# Generating a new table border line only when the terminal width is changed

Tags: bash

The bash script segment below is part of a loop that runs every second. The idea is that it generates the top border of a table, which has three columns. The table is generated to fit within the width of the terminal window, and if the window size changes it should be regenerated to fit the new size.  In order to prevent the row being regenerated every loop, I am trying to store the value in a variable that can simply be printfed on successive loops. The script detects whether the terminal width has changed since the last loop. If the width has changed the row is regenerated to fit the new width. If it has not changed it prints the existing row stored in the variable. This way, only when the user changes the width of the terminal window does the row have to be regenerated, making it faster to draw multiple rows.

Unfortunately it does not work. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong:

```
# Store the previous terminal width (in case it has been resized since the previous loop)
if [ "$term_width" != "" ]; then
    term_width_previous=$(term_width)
fi

# Get the width of the terminal
term_width=$(tput cols)

# Has the table been rezized since previous loop?
if [ "$term_width" != "$term_width_previous" ]; then
    table_resized="yes"
else
    table_resized="no"
fi

# Calculate column widths based on terminal width
col1_width=16
col2_width=16
col3_width=$((term_width - col1_width - col2_width - 13))  # 13 is for padding and borders
col4_width=10

# Syntax: print_table_border "id" "left_border_character" "column_text or ="
print_table_border() {

    border_id=$1

    if [ "$table_resized" = "yes" ]; then
        border_value=""
        border_value+=$(printf " ")
        border_value+=$(printf "$2") ## left border
     
        # first column - either display included text or =======
        if [ "$3" = "═" ]; then
            for ((i = 0; i < col1_width; i++)); do
                border_value+=$(printf "═")
            done
        else
            col1_text=$3
            col1_text_length="${#col1_text}"
            border_value+=$(printf " $col1_text")
            for ((i = 0; i < col1_width - col1_text_length - 1; i++)); do
                border_value+=$(printf " ")
            done
        fi

        border_value+=$(printf "$4")
        for ((i = 0; i < col2_width; i++)); do
            border_value+=$(printf "$5")
        done
        border_value+=$(printf "$6")
        for ((i = 0; i < term_width - col1_width - col2_width - 6; i++)); do
            border_value+=$(printf "$7")
        done
        border_value+=$(printf "$8")
        border_value+=$(printf " \n")
#        printf -v "$border_id" "%s" "$border_value"
       eval "${border_id}=\"$border_value\""
 #      declare -g "${border_id}=$border_value"
        printf "%s" "${!border_id}"  # Print the generated row

    else
        # print the stored row from a variable
        printf "%s" "${!border_id}"  # Print the stored row
    fi
}

print_table_border "sm_top_border" "╔" "═" "╦" "═" "╦" "═" "╗"
```

The first value sent via the funtion is meant to be used as the name of the string that can then be recalled on the next loop, if the terminal has remained the same width. This is the part I am struggling to make work.

This funtion should generate a row for the border, but only if the terminal width has been changed. If it is the same width as the previous time it ran, it should get the previously generated row from the variable that it saved on the previous loop. I don't want to have to generate the row every loop. It will slow everything down when it is generating the entire table. It should only generate the new table layout if the width of the terminal is changed.

The generated variable displays perfectly but the else part of the function does not display. I cannot figure out why. Any ideas?
FYI the variable term_width_previous is set at the bottom of the loop. This way it can compare the terminal width between this loop and the previous loop and know if the terminal width has changed.

I think the issue is to do with the scope of the variable. It does not seem to remember it for the next loop. The complication is that argument $1 is meant to contain the name of the variable that will store the row layout. i.e. It is trying to convert an argument value into a variable name. It then later should retrieve the variable value based of the name of the variable passed through the argument.

Comment: `f(){ local -n id=$1; printf "$id $2\n"; printf -v id hello; }; f var 1; f var 2`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this program can be written much simpler, and even the number of columns can be defined dynamically! I will write it for you and provide comments to enhance your understanding.

```
#!/bin/bash

#get the width of your terminal window
width=$(tput cols)

#get the number of columns from the command line argument
num_cols=$1

#calculate the width of each column
col_width=$(( width / num_cols ))

#calculate the remaining width for the last column
last_col_width=$(( width - (col_width * (num_cols-1)) ))

#generate the top border
top_border="╔"
for (( i=0; i<col_width-2; i++ )); do
    top_border+="═"
done

for (( j=1; j<num_cols; j++ )); do
    top_border+="╦"
    for (( i=0; i<col_width-2; i++ )); do
        top_border+="═"
    done
done

top_border+="╗"

echo "$top_border"
```

ok now,run my script with the desired number of columns as an argument(for example 5):

```
$ bash my_script.sh 5
```